# Select columns having unique and highest value

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables `DOCMETA` and `REVISIONS`:

```
CREATE TABLE "DOCMETA" 
(   
    "DID" NUMBER(*,0),  
    "XIDCPROFILE" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),    
    "XDAMENTITY" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR)
---------------------------------------
-- some other columns
---------------------------------------
)

CREATE TABLE "REVISIONS" 
(   
    "DID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DDOCNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),  
    "DREVISIONID" NUMBER(*,0),  
    "DSTATUS" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) 
---------------------------------------
-- some other columns
---------------------------------------
)
```

Now I want to select **all columns** by combining these two tables joined as `DOCMETA.DID=REVISIONS.DID` where

- `REVISIONS.DSTATUS` should not have the value `EXPIRED` [Query: `REVISIONS.DSTATUS NOT IN ('EXPIRED')`] AND
- `DOCMETA.XIDCPROFILE` should have values either of the `DAMMedia, DAMVideo, DAMFile` [Query: `DOCMETA.XIDCPROFILE IN 'DAMMedia','DAMVideo','DAMFile')`] AND
- `DOCMETA.XDAMENTITY` is not `NULL` and having the pattern `WF/___/DAM` [Query: `DOCMETA.XDAMENTITY LIKE 'WF/___/DAM'`].

Here is a part of `REVISIONS`:

```
DID     DDOCNAME    DREVISIONID     DSTATUS
-------------------------------------------
25066   MHIS015749      92          RELEASED
25074   MHIS021584      1           RELEASED
25128   MHIS004624      5           RELEASED
25137   MHIS005679      7           RELEASED
25138   MHIS005679      8           RELEASED
```

I want to get unique `REVISIONS.DDOCNAME` and the `REVISIONS.DREVISIONID` should be highest. As you can see from the above data these two rows:

```
25137   MHIS005679  7   RELEASED
25138   MHIS005679  8   RELEASED
```

Have same `DDOCNAME` so I want to get that row among these two rows which has highest `DREVISIONID`.

I am stuck to create the query by combining everything with the last two conditions of the unique `DDOCNAME` and highest `DREVISIONID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Join the RESULT table with the following subquery:

```
SELECT DID, DDOCNAME, MAX(DREVISIONID) AS LASTREVISIONID
  FROM REVISIONS
 GROUP BY DID, DDOCNAME
```

having a final query like:

```
SELECT D.DID, R.DDOCNAME, R.REVISIONID, R.DSTATUS
  FROM DOCMETA D INNER JOIN 
       REVISIONS R ON D.DID = R.DID INNER JOIN
       (SELECT DID, DDOCNAME, MAX(DREVISIONID) AS LASTREVISIONID
          FROM REVISIONS
         GROUP BY DID, DDOCNAME) R2 ON R.DID=R2.DID
                                   AND R.DDOCNAME=R2.DDOCNAME
                                   AND r.REVISIONID=R2.LASTREVISIONID
 WHERE D.DSTATUS <> 'EXPIRED'
   AND XIDCPROFILE IN ('DAMMedia','DAMVideo','DAMFile')
   AND XDAMENTITY LIKE 'WF/%/DAM'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *

FROM REVISIONS R

INNER JOIN DOCMETA D

ON R.DID=R.DID

AND R.DREVISIONID=

  (SELECT MAX(DREVISIONID) FROM REVISIONS b WHERE R.DDOCNAME=b.DDOCNAME

  )
```

You can combine this code fragment with the rest of your query.